# [Node.js, sharp]: Make text take up 100% of SVG width

Tags: node.js, svg, sharp

I am using the [sharp image library](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) to add text labels to an image. The only way to add text to an image using sharp is by creating an svg and using the composite function to apply it onto the source image.

```
let width = 100;
let height = 25;
let label = "Loooooooooong Text"; // "Medium Text" "Short"

const label = Buffer.from(`
    <svg width="${width}" height="${height}">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
        <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.25em" fill="#000">${label}</text>
    </svg>
`);

let image = await sharp({
    create: {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        channels: 4,
        background: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, alpha: 1 },
    }
}).composite([{
    input: label,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
}]).png().toBuffer();
```

However, I am having trouble getting the text use the space available in the container properly. Text should be centered vertically and horizontally within the svg. Text should be as tall as it is possible without overflowing the container horizontally.

This is what my code produces with different values for `label`:

[image]

This is ideally what I would like it to produce:

[image]

Additionally, because of an [issue in sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1996) I cannot use `dominant-baseline="middle"` to center my text vertically and instead must use `dy="0.25em"`. I'm not sure if this would change the answer but I thought it noteworthy to include.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `viewBox`

```js
const sharp = require('sharp');

const width = 100;
const height = 25;
const label = "Loooooooooong Text"; // "Medium Text" "Short"

const svg = `
<svg width="${width}" height="${height}" viewBox="0 0 ${height} ${height + 2}">
  <!--this rect should have rounded corners-->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.25em" fill="#000">${label}</text>
</svg>
`;

const svg_buffer = Buffer.from(svg);
const image = sharp({
    create: {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        channels: 4,
        background: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, alpha: 1 },
    }
})
  .composite([{
    input: svg_buffer,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
}])
  .png()
  .toFile('sample.png');
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. Running the exact code above swapping `Loooooooooong Text` for `Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Text` still results in text being cut off horizontally (https://imgur.com/XB9IZ3g). Additionally when changing the value of label to `Short` the text does not fill up the vertical space available as desired (https://imgur.com/3npyX8a). Perhaps the answer still lies with `viewBox` but what is the way to dynamically adjust it for different lengths of text?

Comment: @Nostupidquestions have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to change height accordingly.

```
let width = 100;
let height = 25;
let label = "Loooooooooong  Text ";
let lengthoftext =20;
```

So lets assume this is perfect fitted text scenario.
Now let's think text  is just 10 char.
so you keep width=100 but change height = 50;
and so on you take ratio  heightnew = (20/lengthoftext) *25.
I think all text should be same size you can just make sure what is max length and then you wrap it in next line.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work, given that every character in the string is not the same width.